# openoffice calc use contents of a cell as the formula for another

Tags: openoffice-calc

I searched for this and couldn't find how to do it. I have a cell that has an equation like: "`.25 + .33`" which I want displayed exactly like that. In the cell next to it, I want it to give me the result of that equation, ie, to turn that into "`=.25 - .33`" and show the result. I know I could do it the other way around, typing the formula out, and then using `=FORMULA()` and `REPLACE()` to remove the '=' or even use macros. But that's not what I want in this case. Is there a way to do this? I tried looking at functions like `=INDIRECT()` but no joy.

Comment: Because they are so similar, someone might know the "excel" solution, and not realize it works in openoffice too.

Comment: I removed the `Excel` tag. There is no way in Excel to do this without VBA, which does not apply to `Openoffice`

Comment: For Excel, an internet search provided this result... http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=26974

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints you have chosen, in a word, No.